# Visual Studio - C# - Serial Port - Mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio, arduino, serial-port

I am not sure which serial COM port I should use for connecting my Ardunio device to my Web Application.

When I add a `Serial Port` from the Toolbox it asks for a COM port. On my Ardunio the COM port states `/dev/cu/usbmoden1484`

Which COM Port should I use?

Comment: Sounds like you're more likely to get an answer on the Arduino forum or IRC channel, seems this question is unrelated to TTN altogether? I don't know the answer in any case, I'm not familiar with OSX. Are you sure the port you mentioned isn't the right one? [This thread might be helpful](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/forum/t/port-dev-cu-usbmodem1411-arduino-leonardo/2850)

Answer (score 0):

In Macbook,  `/dev/tty.usbserial` may solve your problem.